Viewing Backed Up Notes With No Internet
If in the event of an internet outage, is there an easy way to access and view my notes files while still with no internet that are backed up on external drive?  It sure doesn’t seem that way.
I got in the habit of saving everything there, especially recipes.
I have an iPhone 14, an iPad that is about 2 years old and Mac desktop around same age that external drive is connected to and constantly backing up.
Thank you.

How do you backup your notes there? Do you make .notesarchive files? Or just backup with iTunes?
